# Prolog breadth-first search (BFS)

Tags: prolog, breadth-first-search

I am new in Prolog and I need a little help. There is this problem:

> The input is a given certain state space, which is edge-labeled tree.
>   Write a program in Prolog that implements a search by BFS method and
>   finds its way to the destination node (g) of the state space with a
>   minimum price.

E.g. : Edge-labeled tree --> (a, g, [a-b/1, a-c/3, b-d/4, b-e/7, c-f/6, c-g/9])

[e.g. tree](http://imageshack.com/a/img674/6118/JfrxUs.jpg)

Thx for help, need it.

EDIT:
This is what i done, but its only for NOT edge-labeled tree. I dont know how add edge-labeled.

```
oh(a,*).
oh(c,a).
oh(b,a).
oh(d,b).
oh(b,e).
oh(c,f).
oh(c,g).
oh(f,h).

bFS(Start, Finish, Path) :-
assertz(gen(Start, *)),
retract(gen(From, To)),
assertz(exp(From, To)),
oh(From, New),
not(gen(New, _)),
not(exp(New, _)),
assertz(gen(New, From)), New = Finish, find(From, [Finish], Path).

find(*, Path, Path).
find(Add, List, Path) :-
oh(Pridavany, Previous),
find(Previous,[Add|List],Path).

 %find(b,[e],Path).
```

Comment: I am total amateur in programming...just try find it on Google but without success.

Comment: Well start with doing some prolog tutorials then. Once you're familiar with the language you can attempt the problem. When you have a specific issue you can't solve, you can come back here. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I try to make it, but for me it is impossible. I am on economic school with a litle programming. Java is fine, but Prolog isnt for me. I try this program search and udnerstand for week and i am stuck in begin.

Answer (score 1):

[These are some good tips on Prolog search](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/courses/771/current/presentations/prolog%20search.pdf).

Try reading these before you see the answer.

The Breadth First Algorithm has been posted on [cs.unm.edu](http://www.cs.unm.edu/~luger/ai-final/code/PROLOG.breadth.html) and works fine with SWI Prolog.

```
state_record(State, Parent, [State, Parent]).

go(Start, Goal) :- 
    empty_queue(Empty_open),
    state_record(Start, nil, State),
    add_to_queue(State, Empty_open, Open),
    empty_set(Closed),
    path(Open, Closed, Goal).

path(Open,_,_) :- empty_queue(Open),
                  write('graph searched, no solution found').

path(Open, Closed, Goal) :- 
    remove_from_queue(Next_record, Open, _),
    state_record(State, _, Next_record),
    State = Goal,
    write('Solution path is: '), nl,
    printsolution(Next_record, Closed).

path(Open, Closed, Goal) :- 
    remove_from_queue(Next_record, Open, Rest_of_open),
    (bagof(Child, moves(Next_record, Open, Closed, Child), Children);Children = []),
    add_list_to_queue(Children, Rest_of_open, New_open), 
    add_to_set(Next_record, Closed, New_closed),
    path(New_open, New_closed, Goal),!.

moves(State_record, Open, Closed, Child_record) :-
    state_record(State, _, State_record),
    mov(State, Next),
    % not (unsafe(Next)),
    state_record(Next, _, Test),
    not(member_queue(Test, Open)),
    not(member_set(Test, Closed)),
    state_record(Next, State, Child_record).

printsolution(State_record, _):- 
    state_record(State,nil, State_record),
    write(State), nl.
printsolution(State_record, Closed) :-
    state_record(State, Parent, State_record),
    state_record(Parent, _, Parent_record),
    member(Parent_record, Closed),
    printsolution(Parent_record, Closed),
    write(State), nl.

add_list_to_queue([], Queue, Queue).
add_list_to_queue([H|T], Queue, New_queue) :-
    add_to_queue(H, Queue, Temp_queue),
    add_list_to_queue(T, Temp_queue, New_queue).
```

The code is free to use, for education purposes.

> We offer them for use, free of charge, for educational purposes only.

We cannot know for sure what you want to achieve, but this is the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, i found this algorithm 2 days before, but still dont know how apply for my problem. :-(